# findOne is null on LOGIN mongoose node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

```
//create new user
app.post('/signup', async function(req,res,next) {

    const saltRounds = 10;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let userEmailExist = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if(userEmailExist)  return res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already exist" }); ///check if user email already exist
    

    bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds)
    .then( function(hashedPassword) {
        
    let newUser = new user({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });
    
    newUser.save(function(error) {
        if(error) throw console.log(error);
        res.send({
            message: 'ok, user is now in db',
            success: true
        })
    });

  });
 
});

//login user
app.post('/login', async function(req,res,next) {
    console.log(req.body.email, req.body.password)

    let userExist = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    console.log(userExist)

    if(!userExist) return res.status(400).send({
        message: 'Email not found'
    });
    
    let validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userExist.password, function(err,result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });

});
```

**Hi, above u can find my code where i register user and next try login, but when i search user in collection it return null...but i don't know why. when i  console.log(req.body.email, req.body.password) they exists in my db but my findOne can't search user email and so userExist return null...can anyone help me? I'm learning MEVN stack**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
let userExist = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec();
```

Comment: Sorry - I since read that `.exec()` and your syntax are functionally the same although `exec()` is recommended because it captures the stack trace if there is an error.